# Why "except Exception" doesn't catch SystemExit?

Tags: python, exception

`isinstance(SystemExit(1), Exception)` evals to True, but this snippet prints `"caught by bare except SystemExit(1,)"`.

```
try:
    sys.exit(0)
except Exception, e:
    print 'caught by except Exception', str(e)
except:
    print 'caught by bare except', repr(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

My testing environment is Python 2.6.

Comment: Did you actually check your statement "`isinstance(SystemExit(1), Exception)` evals to True" on Python 2.6?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`isinstance(SystemExit(1), Exception)`
is False on Python 2.6. Exception hierarchy in this version of Python was changed since Python 2.4.

E.g. `KeyboardInterrupt` is not subclass of `Exception` any more.

See more info http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Comment: PEP 352 provides the rationale: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#exception-hierarchy-changes

Comment: Oh, and GeneratorExit was subsequently moved in 2.6 to inherit directly from BaseException since it is a "system-exiting" exception in some styles of generator-based programming.

Answer (score 11):

`SystemExit` derives from [BaseException directly rather than from Exception](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit).

`Exception` is the parent ["All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions"](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception)

SystemExit is a "system exiting exception" (by definition) and therefore doesn't derive from `Exception`. In your example, if you used `BaseException`, it would work as per your original assumptions.

Answer (score 8):

Your error is in the very first sentence of your question:

```
>>> isinstance(SystemExit(1), Exception)
False
```

`SystemExit` is not a subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: Thanks, I found the real error, is in Python 2.3, `isinstance(SystemExit(1), Exception)` is True. And with Python 2.3, the testing code prints `"caught by except Exception"`. For Python 2.6, this is correct.